# Laravel lag spikes

Tags: php, apache, laravel, timeout, benchmarking

when i use the apache benchmark in Laravel, i got some serious lag at random request.
Sometimes an error happens that tell me the script is too long to run.

this come from the files :

```
Vendor\Symfony\Component\Finder\Iterator\DateRangeFilterIterator.php
```

In this function :

```
public function accept()
{
    $fileinfo = $this->current();

    if (!file_exists($fileinfo->getRealPath())) {
        return false;
    }

    $filedate = $fileinfo->getMTime();
    foreach ($this->comparators as $compare) {
        if (!$compare->test($filedate)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

[Here is the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Kwdm.png)

[And the report when i set the accept function to return true;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxZqH.png)

If i remove the function and just remplace by return true; the lag stop but this function probably serve to somethings no ? I hope you have a solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the file system is the bottle neck. Try running your tests after you run the below commands;

```
composer dump-autoload -o
artisan config:cache
artisan route:cache
```

They should set up some caches so laravel doesn't hit the filesystem so hard.